# Why am I getting IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported channel configuration?

Tags: java, android, audio, audiorecord

I'm using AudioRecord to collect audio data from a headphone jack on Android like so:

```
int frequency = 44100;
int channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO;
int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(frequency, channelConfiguration, audioEncoding);
AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, frequency, channelConfiguration, audioEncoding, bufferSize);
audioRecord.startRecording();
```

However, I get an error that says

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported channel configuration.
```

I haven't found anything helpful online, so I was wondering if anyone else had this issue.

Comment: Because it isn't supporting that combination of frequency, channel config, and encoding.  I'm seeing posts that say the emulator only supports 8K Hz.  Are you using real hardware?

Comment: Also could be that you're trying to record from an output with `AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO`.

Comment: @GabeSechan Hi, I'm using a smasung galaxy 2, so 44100 should be okay.

Comment: @CaseyB Should I try using AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if this is what CaseyB meant, but I changed AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO to AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO. This made the error go away.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant.

Comment: for me it actually produced the same error with CHANNEL_IN_MONO and worked OK with CHANNEL_IN_STEREO

Answer (score 1):

when you use record, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO.
when you use play, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Change `AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO` to `AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_FRONT`